# How to make a bootable ISO file

Tags: boot, usb, iso, bootable

I want to convert a bin file to a bootable ISO.

I follow the instructions in this [link,"How Can I Make a Bootable CD With ISOLINUX?"](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=ISOLINUX) to create a ISO file.

I put my bin file in images folder, isolinux.bin and syslinux.cfg in isolinux, memdisk in kernel.

I burn the ISO file into USB and boot my computer from the USB.  I use dd commend.

```
dd if=file.ISO of=/dev/sdb
```

It shows

> FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.

I find someone said that the message means your ISO is not bootable.  I don't know where is the problem.  I pretty sure that my bin file is a bootable image.

Besides, I don't know is it helpful: I can open the USB in Ubuntu, but in Windows, it asks me format the USB.

Comment: How did you "_burn the ISO file into USB_" (what commands did you use)? Please add this to your question as if you had included this detail originally. Do not write "Edit" or "Update". Do not reply here in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO image you have created only boots if written to optical media (CD, DVD, or a Blu-Ray disc).

USB sticks boot differently. You need to add a boot record to your image file before writing it to the USB device.

See [Isohybrid](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid).

Comment: This does not answer how to make a bootable ISO.